# clearInterval() doesn’t work properly. Intervals stack on eachother

Tags: javascript, html, intervals

Hello everyone I have been having trouble with the setInterval() and clearInterval() functions.

I can’t seem to figure out why it’s not working, been searching for hours trying multiple solutions

I want the user to be able to click on a zone, afterwards it spawns an enemy, you kill the enemy, another respawns

I have it like this but the problem I am having is that when the enemy refreshes, it’s health immediately drops to 0 and its almost like the setIntervals are stacking on top of each other because after it respawns it starts taking double damage.

If anyone could give me insight on this that would be great!

```
function selectelwynnforestzone(){
var refreshtankattackinterval = setInterval(tankattackenemy, tankattackspeed);
```

Codepen link
https://codepen.io/jonloft/pen/eYMmYQj

(It may look a little wonky but just click the Elwynn forest button)

Comment: Each call to `setInterval()` sets up a new interval timer independent of all the other interval timers.

Comment: Take out `var`. You're setting a local variable instead of the global variable.

Comment: Please post the [mre] here, not as a link to codepen.